# «En el quinto día» vs. «Al quinto día» ¿Qué diferencia hay?

Tags: preposiciones

Si uno quiere decir:

> "On the fifth day...."

¿Hay una diferencia entre estas dos frases?

> En el quinto día...
>
> Al quinto día...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia entre "en el quinto día" y "al quinto día" es sutil.

"En el quinto día" es un adjunto adverbial que se puede usar **cuando se detalla qué pasa (o pasó, o pasará) cada día a lo largo de un proceso**. Es bastante común omitir la preposición "en":

- **(En) El primer día** podemos visitar los museos.
- **(En) El segundo día** podemos recorrer las plazas.

[...]

- **(En) El quinto día** salimos para ...

"Al quinto día" sugiere **el paso del tiempo respecto de un hecho que sirve como referencia**, y "al" obviamente no puede omitirse. Por ejemplo, en el Evangelio encontramos la oración:

- **Al tercer día** resucitó de entre los muertos. (Significado: Al tercer día de haber muerto.)

Otro ejemplo:

- Empecé a trabajar y **al quinto día** (de haber empezado a trabajar) ya quería renunciar.

Comment: ¿Quieres agregar que "al quinto día" es más común?

Comment: @aparente001 El punto no es cuál es más común, sino en qué se diferencian. Si hablamos de frecuencia, podemos decir que "el quinto día" es más común que "en el quinto día". Pero entre "(en) el quinto día" y "al quinto día" existe una diferencia a nivel conceptual, no de frecuencia de uso.

Comment: Pero si estás de acuerdo que «En el quinto día» es más común que «Al quinto día», entonces creo que conviene señalar esto (**además** de dar la explicación completa que ya diste), porque esa información es muy útil en la práctica para los estudiantes del español.  Pero a fin de cuentas es tu post y no tienes que aceptar mi propuesta.

Comment: ¿No implica la primera definición la segunda? Me parece que, cuando hay un proceso, el inicio del proceso sirve como referencia. Sería malo decir "Al primer día, podemos visitar los museos, al segundo día podemos recorrer las plazas" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Sí, **estaría mal** (NO sería malo) o al menos no sonaría bien decir lo que propones. Para detallar un programa, debes decir: *El primer día haremos tal cosa, el segundo día haremos tal otra.* Si usas "al", SIEMPRE remite a un hecho anterior: *Al primer día (de haber llegado) me di cuenta de que habíamos ido al lugar equivocado.*

Answer (score -1):

it is much simpler, al = a + el, we are comparing a with en, two different prepositions, generally, al quinto día means that a subordinada is omited but understood al tercer dia (de estar enterrado)